# ACE_TAO + OpenSSL - Problem with server initialization

Tags: ace, tao

I have problem with initialization of server which is using ace_tao library and OpenSSL (without SSL option enabled everything works fine). The Problem is in SSLIOP_Factory. I will attach server.config and output log from ace_tao below (OpenSSL 1.1.1, ACE_TAO 6.5.7):

```
ACE (3472|2568) DSB::instance, repo=01277740, name=SSLIOP_Factory type=00000000 => 00000000
TAO (3472|2568) Unable to load protocol <SSLIOP_Factory>, No such file or directory
ACE (3472|2568) SCG:<dtor=0226F7C4> - new repo=01277740
```

```
dynamic SSLIOP_Factory Service_Object *
  TAO_SSLIOP:_make_TAO_SSLIOP_Protocol_Factory()
  "-SSLAuthenticate SERVER_AND_CLIENT -SSLPrivateKey 'PEM:XXXXXXX/server-key.pem' -SSLCertificate 'PEM:XXXXXXX/server-cert.pem' -SSLCAFile 'PEM:XXXXXXXXXX/cacert.pem'"

dynamic Advanced_Resource_Factory Service_Object*
  TAO_Strategies:_make_TAO_Advanced_Resource_Factory ()
  "-ORBProtocolFactory SSLIOP_Factory"

static Client_Strategy_Factory  "-ORBConnectStrategy blocked"
```

XXXXX - just for hide full path to certs.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

See [github](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/issues/1031) for the same question with solution.